# Debugging large programs in C#

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a big program written in C# which takes ~20 minutes to complete. The program is divided into multiple stages and flow of information is sequential. If my program fails after say step 2, I have to re-run it from the beginning. Is there any smarter way of saving information after each step in some in-memory object/service etc, which can be directly used to run the 3rd step. This is not a very good description but I need to debug the program at the end but for it I have to rerun it from the start every time. Is there any industrial practice for such cases?

Thanks
Shiv

Comment: Unit Testing. Unit Testing. Unit Testing.

Comment: @BradChristie: What about unit testing? Who says the problem can be sub divided?  What about 'acts of God' ?

Comment: @leppie - I have yet to see a non-trivial program that can't be.

Comment: @leppie: I haven't run across a problem yet that can't (in some form/fashion) be debugged and solidified with unit testing. There are initializers and cleanup processes for whatever needs to be tackled. And where VS's debugging lacks, there are a plethora of libraries available for almost every situation.

Comment: @IsaacCambron: Good luck unit testing the Linux kernel, for example  ;p Even if it was possible, coverage will be pathetic at best. Edit: Coverage ito functional coverage, not just code coverage.

Comment: Everyone says 'UNIT TESTING', yes good, but now you hit an error, what then? Sure you can handle it, but the OP asks how he/she can persist the state of the process. Only 1 of 4 answers currently actually covers that..

Answer (score 6):

How is data flowing between steps? If the flow of data is well defined (preferably one channel). you can implement a "record" and "play" module. This will know to receive to record to file (by serializing) the data it gets on one end and play it on the other. If it is not connected from the input, it will play the file or something like that. Then you connect the player to the output of stage 2 one time. and when debugging play it directly to the 3rd step

Comment: +1 For trying to answer the question, instead of shouting 'UNIT TESTING'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Unit testing
2. Mock Objects
3. In-memory db

Answer (score 2):

Learn modern programming practices. Especially:

- Automated testing
- Unit testing.

The later allows you to test the individual parts and should be done in concert with something called "continuous integration". The first allows you to have those tests run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing would be my approach to a large debugging situation. Write down a number of test cases and values etc and off you go. Would take a while but would prevent running through over and over again.